# There's some way to add a wrapper around posted images?

Tags: plugins, images, filters

I need to add a wrapper (I'll use `<figure>` in my example) around images posted through the editor, with a variable depending on the size image is being posted (thumbnail, medium, large, full), something like:

```
<figure class="$size">
    <a rel="attachment" href="....>
         <img... />
    </a>
</figure>
```

I already solved the first step, adding the wrapper with a filter through `image_send_to_editor`, but I can't find a way to get the image size so I can add it to the class.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

The `image_send_to_editor` hook passes a whole range of parameters, not just the html. One of them is the size. To get it, hook your filter passing an 8 as the number of supported parameters:

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'my_filter_cb'), 10, 8);
```

and modify your function header to grab them all:

```
function my_filter_cb ($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
    ...
}
```